# Running (Generate PDF) soffice LibreOffice on Windows PHP exec() doesn't work

Tags: php, windows, pdf, iis, libreoffice

I'm trying to generate a pdf from docx using soffice so i try it on apache linux and its works, but im trying in windows server 2012 and IIS 6.2.

If i run this command on CMD its works:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export --outdir  ../../storage/app/ACTIVO/2019-03/3404/docx/ ../../storage/app/ACTIVO/2019-03/3404/docx/documento_word.docx
```

So in PHP I try this:

```
$comando = 'soffice --headless --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export --outdir  ../../storage/app/ACTIVO/2019-03/3404/docx/ ../../storage/app/ACTIVO/2019-03/3404/docx/documento_word.docx';
$var = exec($comando);
var_dump($var);
```

And its give me "NULL"

The same happen when i try to use soffice --version in PHP.

I give full permission to IUSR in C:\Program Files\Libreoffice and storage/app have permission too. In IIS the Anonymous Authentication is enabled.

I run in php and its return " **string(26) "iis apppool\defaultapppool"** "

```
$var = exec('whoami');
var_dump($var);
```

I don't know how can i do to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, creating a new user in Windows with low permission to run a command like that user.
I
nstall [SysinternalsSuite](https://download.sysinternals.com/files/SysinternalsSuite.zip) to run psexec command, the zip is descompressed in C:\

So, the line that i change was:

```
$comando = 'soffice --headless --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export --outdir  ../../storage/app/ACTIVO/2019-03/3404/docx/ ../../storage/app/ACTIVO/2019-03/3404/docx/documento_word.docx';
```

to:

```
$comando = '"C:\SysinternalsSuite\psexec.exe" -u DOMAIN\USER -p PASSWORD "C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.exe" --headless --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export --outdir  C:\inetpub\wwwroot\storage\app\ACTIVO\2019-03\3404\docx\ C:\inetpub\wwwroot\storage\app\ACTIVO\2019-03\3404\docx\documento_word.docx';
```